# read and decrypt cakephp cookies in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, cookies

Is there any way to read and decrypy the cakephp cookies in javascript? i can read out the encrypted value, but it's not of much help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Those values are encrypted with a secret key. To decrypt them, you'd need to make the key available to Javascript, which means making it available to anyone out there who's looking at your site. It's not impossible to do it, but I'd seriously question how wise it is to do so. What are you actually trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: i will this as the correct answer if you post it as one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those values are encrypted with a secret key. To decrypt them, you'd need to make the key available to Javascript, which means making it available to anyone out there who's looking at your site. It's not impossible to do it, but I'd seriously question how wise it is to do so.

Comment: Actually, at a much simpler level: if it can be decrypted by Javascript on the client, there's no point in encrypting it to begin with. :)